# When flying with an infant, what airport security restrictions for breast milk/formula/baby food apply?

Tags: infant, food, flying

We're planning on taking a short (1-2 hour) air trip in a couple of months.  Our son will be 11 months old by then.

Given the delays with getting through security, the amount of time in advance we'll need to arrive at the gate, and the duration of the flight, we're assuming we'll need to feed him at least once during the trip.

However, with the restrictions of airport security, we're not sure if we'll be able to bring food with us.

Can we bring bottled breast milk?  Powdered formula with water?  Jars of baby food?  All of those would need to exceed the fluid volume restrictions in place for carry-on baggage within the US.  Are exceptions made for infants?  Would glass jars for the baby food be an issue?

Comment: I vote to close. This is too localized and time-sensitive. The rules change frequently and are never consistent across countries.

Comment: @Javid Valid points, and tbh I was concerned that this might be considered too localized before I asked. However, while the rules do change frequently, there's a good chance specific references such as the one Darwy posted in her answer will be updated to reflect any changes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[TSA](http://www.tsa.gov/travelers/airtravel/children/formula.shtm) requires that you declare that you have breastmilk with you at the security checkpoint.

Put the bottles in their own plastic bag and there shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: The TSA also allows jarred baby food "in reasonable quantities" (yes, that's subject to interpretation). Like breast milk or premixed formula, you need to declare it, and they will examine the jars, but unlike in Europe, they actually have the brains to not make you open the jars.

Answer (score 4):

In the past, we have pretty much brought anything we wanted.  All of the things were obviously baby food, in reasonable quantities, in original packaging, and unopened (expect for one, perhaps).  The containers were small, as they are, but I don't think they technically fit the limits for other liquids.  And the baby was with us.  They make you open the bag and test the stuff with their sticks and what not.  But no one ever questioned it any further.

They might make you dump whatever milk or water you have currently in the bottle.

The TSA or respective equivalent agency is of course the final authority on this; the above is just practical experience.

Answer (score 1):

The rules I know say that **you may bring whatever the child needs for the trip.** We've stretched that fairly wide without any trouble - but that was neither US nor UK.